# Add struct or pointer to struct to slice

Tags: go

Say I have structs like so:

```
type Foo struct {
  F string `zoom:"1"`
}

type Bar struct {
  F string `zoom:"2"`
}

type Baz struct {
  F string `zoom:"3"`
}
```

Say I wanted to create a func that can extract the f field from each struct, it might look like:

```
func extractField(s []struct{}){
  for _, v := range s {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(v{})
    f, _ := t.FieldByName("F")
    v, ok := f.Tag.Lookup("zoom")
  }
}
```

is there a way to pass the structs to extractField? If I do this:

```
extractField([]struct{}{Foo, Bar, Baz})
```

I get this error:

```
Type Foo is not an expression
Type Bar is not an expression
Type Baz is not an expression
```

I just want to pass the 3 structs to the extractField func.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could figure out how to do this, is like so:

```
type Foo struct {
    F string `zoom:"1"`
}

type Bar struct {
    F string `zoom:"2"`
}

type Baz struct {
    F string `zoom:"3"`
}


func extractField(s []interface{}){
    for _, v := range s {
        t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
        f, _ := t.FieldByName("F")
        v, ok := f.Tag.Lookup("zoom")
        fmt.Println(v,ok)
    }
}

func main(){

    extractField([]interface{}{Foo{},Bar{},Baz{}})  // <<<< here

}
```

not sure if there is a way to pass a struct without "instantiating it" first.

Answer (score 1):

The original code looks like it follows a JavaScript approach, where a function would mutate an object. Go is a little bit different, where it's more common to self-mutate.

For example:

```
type Generic struct {
  field string
}

func (generic *Generic) Value () string {
  return generic.field
}

someObject := &Generic{
  field: "some value",
}

log.Print(someObject.Value()) // Outputs "some value"
```

If you're coming from the JavaScript world, think of structs a little bit like an object/class that can contain attributes and functions. Structs are merely a definition until an instance is instantiated. This differs from JavaScript where the definition of the object and the data are both defined at the same time.

As the other answer points out, an interface is another similar approach to dealing with this.

**Clarification**

In JavaScript terms, the OP is attempting to do something akin to:

```
class Foo {...}
class Bar {...}
class Baz {...}

extractField(Foo, Bar, Baz)
```

In JS-speak, this would pass a class definition to the extractField method. You would still have to instantiate an instance of a class if you want to manipulate/read from it, like:

```
extractField(new Foo(), new Bar(), new Baz())
```

This is basically what is being accomplished with

```
extractField([]interface{}{Foo{},Bar{},Baz{}})
```

I think the problem you're running into is the Foo/Bar/Baz structs are instantiated, but the nested F struct is not.

Comment: upvoted but I think you missed the point of the OP - OP is trying to pass structs in a slice to another func. But I can't pass a struct{} itself, I can only pass a struct{}{} instance? I am trying to pass the struct type itself, not an value/expression.

Comment: My point was you can't pass in a dynamically instantiated struct/slice. Instantiation is required beforehand (as you already found out). Mentally, you have to separate the _definition_ of a struct from an _instance_ of the struct.

Comment: @Corey ultimately just trying to reduce verbosity in the OP - I wanted to instantiate each class/struct after it had been passed, not before - unfortunately with Golang you cannot pass types around, only expressions, as tar as I can tell.  I would like to pass the definition of a struct in Golang, but I guess you can't. Shame.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman - indeed, this was one of the biggest pills to swallow when shifting mindset from JS-->Go (for me anyway).

Comment: @Corey yeah the problem with not being able to pass types is that you have import things at the top of the file, and with cyclic imports being forbidden (unlike Java and Node.js) this is a huge constraint that I have hit a few times with a go project I am working on, maybe will get better at avoiding it but so far not so much. Now I know why so many go projects have all the files in one folder...

Answer (score 0):

The overall problem seems like a much better match for an interface type.

```
type HasF interface {
    GetF() string
}
```

It's easy enough to define these methods, *e.g.*

```
func (foo Foo) GetF() string { return foo.F }
```

Your method to iterate over them becomes almost trivial

```
func extractField(s []HasF) {
    for _, v := range s {
        fmt.Printf(v.GetF())
    }
}

func main() {
    extractField([]HasF{Foo{},Bar{},Baz{}})
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/uw0T7TGVC0n has a complete version of this.

Comment: yes, but how do they pass the type like here `decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)`? how is `r.Body` passed? Is r.Body a struct or interface or?

Comment: [`json.NewDecoder`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#NewDecoder) takes a **value** of type `io.Reader`; that happens to be an interface type, but it is a thing from which you can read and not a type _per se_.